# QChart how to remove white border around the QScatterSeries

Tags: c++, qt, qchart

Would you have any idea how to remove the white border around the point when QScatterSeries is used? Is it possible?

The idea behind is that when I plot a lot of values (on the image are 100 only) close to each other, the points will become white/disapper because of the borders.

[image: QScatterSeries plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a transparent border color via [setBorderColor()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscatterseries.html#borderColor-prop) or a transparent pen color via [setPen()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscatterseries.html#setPen).

```
series->setBorderColor(Qt::transparent);
```

Or

```
series->setPen(QColor(Qt::transparent));
```

See [ScatterChart Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-scatterchart-example.html).

You can also disable QPen drawing line at all using [Qt::PenStyle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#PenStyle-enum)

```
series->setPen(QPen(Qt::PenStyle::NoPen));
```